# Remote acces my Raspberry Pi from a subdomain

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, raspbian-buster

I am wondering if I can remote access my Pi's from a subdomain.

EX (assuming that I own example.com):

```
pi1.example.com
pi2.example.com
```

Basically both the Pi's share my network and from LAN I can access them as let's say `192.168.0.10` and `192.168.0.20`.

How, or even is it possible to mask them as subdomains of `example.com`?

Comment: this question is already answered by the accepted answer here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58888/can-i-identify-my-pi-by-domain-name-in-a-lan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I identify my PI by domain name in a LAN?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58888/can-i-identify-my-pi-by-domain-name-in-a-lan)